# Samba Server as domain controller

Tags: samba

I am using centos 6.2 on my system. I want to make samba server as PDC to join the clients computers operating systems i.e  xp,windows 7 and share their  files & directories.Currently I have 200 PC running both windows xp and win 7.

The question I want to as is does samba 3.5.10 has a capacity to join 200 computers as a domain controller & authenticate the users ?

thanks
garden

---

Thanks for your guidence.Well at the moment I am using CentOS 6.2 and samba is installed using yum command. It is amazing that I can join samba as a domain comtroller of  200 clients machines. By the way what is samba maximum limit for joining number of clients PC's.

Comment: AD or old-style domain controller?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. You can take a look at the official [redhat 6 documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-File_and_Print_Servers.html#s1-Samba) you will see that :

What Samba can do:

- Serve directory trees and printers to Linux, UNIX, and Windows clients
- Assist in network browsing (with or without NetBIOS)
- Authenticate Windows domain logins
- Provide Windows Internet Name Service (WINS) name server resolution
- Act as a Windows NT®-style Primary Domain Controller (PDC)
- Act as a Backup Domain Controller (BDC) for a Samba-based PDC
- Act as an Active Directory domain member server
- Join a Windows NT/2000/2003/2008 PDC

What Samba cannot do:

- Act as a BDC for a Windows PDC (and vice versa)
- Act as an Active Directory domain controller